# Центрирование в CSS

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Как отцентрировать вертикальную полосу в CSS? Сама полоса сделана:

```
.vline {
    border-right: 1px solid white;  
    height: 70px;   
}
```

Comment: margin: auto пробовали?

Comment: А можете добавить деталей и запускаемого кода?

Answer (score 1):

Если полоса - блочный элемент, и нужно выровнять ее по центру родительского контейнера, в котором больше ничего не лежит, то можно так:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Если в родительском контейнере что-то лежит и вам не хочется разбираться с flex, то можно так:

```
.container{
  position:relative;
}

.container .vline{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Если вам нужна эта полоса поверх всего по центру экрана, то можно так:

```
.vline{
  position:fixed;
  left:50vw;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Либо конкретизируйте вопрос и добавьте больше кода.

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно сделать это через "position: fixed". [Пример](https://jsbin.com/jicupifuze)
2. Можно сделать это в контейнере с помощью смещения внутри контейнера. [Пример](https://jsbin.com/cibeqicere)
3. Можно сделать это с помощью Flexbox. [Пример](https://output.jsbin.com/fitovuruqo).

В зависимости от того,как будут располагаться остальные элементы - будет изменятся ответ.
Добавьте пример использования.

Comment: А можете код перенести со стороннего ресурса сюда?